# Taking one value from a table

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

sorry if this has been asked before but I everything I found has not helped.

I'm looking to set a value from a table to the text property of a label. This is what I have so far:

In a separate class with the connection string "conn" -

(SQL Region)

```
Public Const SELECT_1 As String = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [TableTimes] 
WHERE [timeID] = @PKey"
```

(Methods Region)

```
Public Shared Function returnOneRow(PrimaryKey As Integer) As TableTimes
            Dim returnRow As New TableTimes(0)
            Dim conn As New SqlConnection
            conn.connectionstring = Conn.getConnectionString

            Dim command As New SqlCommand
            command.connection = conn
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            command.CommandText = SQL.SELECT_1
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PKey", PrimaryKey)
            Try
                conn.Open()
                Dim dR As IDataReader = command.ExecuteReader
                If dR.Read() Then
                    returnRow.timeID = PK
                    If Not IsDBNull(dR(Fields.linkID)) Then returnRow.linkID = dR(Fields.linkID)
                    If Not IsDBNull(dR(Fields.dateTime)) Then returnRow.dateTime = dR(Fields.dateTime)
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(Err.Description)
            End Try
            Return returnRow
        End Function
```

And then back in the main form I am trying to set the dateTime to a label based on what primary key (timeID) I enter as a parameter. This is the closest I can think of:

```
label.Text = (Tables.TableTimes.returnOneRow(1).dateTime).ToString
```

I know the output should be "2016-02-04 10:00:00" for the row with the timeID of 1 based on my table data, but instead it returns "0001-01-01 12:00:00" no matter what parameter I enter.

I would prefer to not change my method or sql statement and just change how I call the function in the main form if that's possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you debugged your code? I'll wager not. Place a breakpoint at the top of the code and step through it, line by line. You can then ensure that execution follows the path you expect. At each step, examine all your variables and other relevant expressions to ensure that they are what you expect them to be. As soon as you find a situation that is not as you expect, you've found an issue. Even if nothing else, at least you can tell us where the issue occurred and what the data was in use at the time. Otherwise, we're just guessing.

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags.  Please don't include tags in the title.

Comment: Read how to create a [mcve]